# Promises made before hitting puberty

Tags: oaths

I made a lot of promises to Allah before hitting puberty. I still remember some of those promises. Should I fulfill the promises I remember or do they not count since I wasn't baligh.

Comment: Isn't this question the same? https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62194/making-a-promise-to-allah-before-puberty

Answer (score 1):

To be honest there is a major ikhtlaf on when a child begins to be accountable if you search it there are lots of fatwas and different opinions on the topic so just to be safe you should probably fulfil those promises if possible. However I will list one opinion here:

if a boy has a wet dream or a girl has her first period then they are baligh but if they don’t then it’s by age 15 years. (Radd al-mukhtar)

but plz note again of the major ikhtlaf there may be Other signs But may not be agreed upon in some cases so I just advise you should just make the promises up and also I’m not a scholar.